# Box model for a Image board CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend

Hello guys and girls I Have been working on a Image board as a learning project for the past few week and have run into a bit of a snag with CSS styling mostly in how I should style the Post and it content. What I'm wanting to build would look something like this.

[image]

For now the way I'm doing this is by having a div hold a img and another div with the post_content and a header inside of that. and setting it to Display:flex,row

A problem with this would be that the post/header div would out grow the container post div and would make text run off screen. I tried fixing this by giving the post and the img a fixed size 20%/80%. this worked well till i resize the page and the gap between the img and the div grew larger as i size up the page.

here is a sample post any help would be awesome and as always ill be around to answer any questions.

```css
#flex_content {
  display: flex;
}
#flex_post {
  width: 80%;
}
#post_header {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#thumbnail {
  width: 10em;
  height: auto;
}
#post {
  background-color: #333 !important;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
#post {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #F4E8AF;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#img {
  width: 20%
}
#post_contnet{
    width:80%;
}
```

```html
<div id='post'>
  <div id="header">
    <a href="images/1455249371 ">1455249371.png </a>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div id="flex_content">
    <div id="img">
      <img id='thumbnail' src="images/1455249371 ">
    </div>
    <div id='flex_post'>
      <div id="reply_header">
        <b>Anonymous</b> 10:56
        <ahref='chan.php?post=83'>>>No.83</a>
          [<a href='thread.php?thread=67'>Reply</a>]
          <br />
      </div>
      <div id='post_contnet'>
        [Transparent]
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what the `float` property was made for... Any reason not to use it? Like [this example here](http://jsbin.com/doceliceme/edit?html,css,output). You can reduce the HTML markup required and simply float the image.

Comment: @misterManSam I think I was using float in a older version of my code but I was having a problem with the post div not getting its height. When i looked in the inspector it would show that the height was 1px tall. I guess i took the float out and tried doing it with a flex box thinking it would be able to handle the height problem and also the resizing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try this:

```css
#thumbnail {
  width: 10em;
  height: auto;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='post'>
  <div id="flex_content">
    <div id="img">
        <img id='thumbnail' src="1455249371.png">
        <div id="header">
          <a href="images/1455249371 ">1455249371.png </a>
        </div>
        <b>Anonymous</b> 10:56
        <a href='chan.php?post=83'>>>No.83</a>
        [<a href='thread.php?thread=67'>Reply</a>]
        <br />
        <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>
        
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
       
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes this with my removing of the 20% on the img works just like i wanted it to thank you vary much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed this while just cleaning up my code all i did was remove the width:20% from the img tag and boom bam boom it works